# Generating java binding classes using XML file without XSD schema file? Using any Castor or JAXB framework

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, castor

I have a requirement to create java model classes  (binding classes) from XML files. Unfortunately I don't have XSD schema. There are many already existing XML's.

Strangely , Castor or JAXB both use XSD schema to generate binding model classes. What if you don't have a schema? Not all XML are created using Schema!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a schema inference tool like [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html). It can produce `xsd` from `xml`. You could then tweak the generated schema or just feed it straight to JAXB/Castor etc.

Comment: Tks. as mentioned in other comment. I tried trang / XMLSpy to generate XSD. But the problem is both XSD's are very different. Infact XML spy is validating it's XSD against my XML examples but failing against trang generated schema!!! also i see XML spy generated schema has DATA from my XML example!!

Comment: You could map the classes by hand. It just takes a few annotations.

Comment: My XML's are very large and complex. I never mapped classes though.If  i need to map each tag /element it may get cumbersome!

Answer (score 2):

The reason that XML binding technologies do not generate Java classes from XML is that it is an extra level of complexity:

- Is that single XML element really a single element or a collection of size 1?
- The data in the sample XML looks like an int, but is String content allowed?

You have a couple of options.  The first is you can use a tool to generate an XML schema from the XML and then generate the classes from that.  Or you could annotate your existing classes to map them to XML:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: Tks.  I now understand that why XSD is selected by castor/JAXB not XML.  But I have seen in past and now that there are XML's created  without XSD/DTD. Anyway..I don't have XSD  so i tried trang / XMLSpy to generate XSD. But the problem is both XSD's are very different. Infact XML spy is validating it's XSD against my XML examples but failing against trang generated schema!!! also i see XML spy generated schema has DATA from my XML example!!